Conectar a los Webservices de Hospedajes del Ministerio de Interior
Estoy intentando conectar con Php Soap a los webservices del Ministerio de Interior para el envio de los Partes de entrada de viajeros en establecimientos de hospedaje.
Los datos de acceso al Servicio de Comunicación en los entornos de pruebas y producción son:
Endpoint pruebas-> https://hospedajes.pre-ses.mir.es/hospedajes-web/ws/v1/comunicacion
Endpoint producción-> https://hospedajes.ses.mir.es/hospedajes-web/ws/v1/comunicacion
Para poder conectarse al servicio, previamente hay que tener en cuenta las siguientes indicaciones:
• Los servicios web publicados implementan seguridad básica HTTP. Esto requiere del envío de una cabecera con las siguientes características:
Clave: 'Authorization'
Valor: 'Basic ', con token=usuario:contraseña codificado en Base64
La comunicación extremo a extremo se establece a través de un túnel SSL para lo que se requiere de la importación de un certificado provisto en el almacén de certificados de confianza de la aplicación cliente.
Mi script en principio es este:
<?php
// Envio de partes de viajeros SES-HOSPES
$local_cert = 'fnmt.pem';// Ruta a certificado previamente convertido de PFX a PEM
$soapUrl = "https://hospedajes.pre-ses.mir.es/hospedajes-web/ws/v1/comunicacion"; // Url Entorno Pruebas
$soapUri = "https://hospedajes.pre-ses.mir.es/hospedajes-web/ws/vl"; // Uri 
$username = "1234"; // Nombre de Usuario
$password = "pass"; // Contraseña
// Instanciar el cliente SOAP
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'local_cert' => $local_cert,
    'uri' => $soapUri,
    'location' => $soapUrl,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
            'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false
            ],
            'http' => [
            'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
            ]
 
        ]),
    ));

try {
    $response = $client->__soapCall("YourSoapMethod", ["param1" => "value1", "param2" => "value2"]); // Replace with your SOAP method and parameters
    print_r($response);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    echo "Error: {$fault->getMessage()}";
}
?>

la direccion uri es inventada, no proporcionan ninguna, asi como tampoco el wsdl.
al ejecutar el error que da es 'Error: Unauthorized'
Alguna idea de por donde esta la solucion?

<?php
// Datos conexion
$endpointprod = "https://hospedajes.ses.mir.es/hospedajes-web/ws/v1/comunicacion";
$ruta_certificado = "C:\laragon\www\ses-hospes\fnmt.pem";
$usuario = "usuario";
$contrasena = "contrasena";
$token = base64_encode("$usuario:$contrasena");
// Llamada al servidor
echo "Conectando con el Ministerio del Interior...<br/><br/>";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpointprod);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $ruta_certificado);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    "Authorization: Basic " . $token . "",
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

// Respuesta del servidor
if ($ret === false) {
    echo "Error sending " . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ret;
}


  <solicitud>
    <codigoEstablecimiento>texto</codigoEstablecimiento>
    <comunicacion>
      <contrato>
        <referencia>texto</referencia>
        <fechaContrato>2024-12-05+01:00</fechaContrato>
        <fechaEntrada>2024-12-05T09:18:29.357+01:00</fechaEntrada>
        <fechaSalida>2024-12-05T09:18:29.357+01:00</fechaSalida>
        <numPersonas>1</numPersonas>
        <numHabitaciones>1</numHabitaciones>
        <internet>true</internet>
        <pago>
          <!--Tipos de pago: [EFECT, TARJT, PLATF, TRANS, MOVIL, TREG, OTRO, DESTI]-->
          <tipoPago>EFECT</tipoPago>
          <fechaPago>2024-12-05+01:00</fechaPago>
          <medioPago>texto</medioPago>
          <titular>texto</titular>
          <!--Formato mm/aaaa siendo mm un mes entre 01 y 12 y aaaa un año del 2023 en adelante-->
          <caducidadTarjeta>12/2027</caducidadTarjeta>
        </pago>
      </contrato>
      <persona>
        <!--Roles: VI. Debe haber, al menos, una persona con el rol de viajero (VI). El número de personas informadas deberá coincindir con el número de personas establecido para la comunicación-->
        <rol>VI</rol>
        <nombre>texto</nombre>
        <apellido1>texto</apellido1>
        <apellido2>texto</apellido2>
        <!--Tipos documentos: [NIF, NIE, PAS, OTRO, CIF]-->
        <tipoDocumento>NIF</tipoDocumento>
        <numeroDocumento>00000000T</numeroDocumento>
        <soporteDocumento>texto</soporteDocumento>
        <fechaNacimiento>2024-12-05+01:00</fechaNacimiento>
        <!--País código ISO alfa-3: [ESP, ARG, ...]-->
        <nacionalidad>ESP</nacionalidad>
        <!--Sexo: [H, M, O]-->
        <sexo>H</sexo>
        <direccion>
          <direccion>texto</direccion>
          <direccionComplementaria>texto</direccionComplementaria>
          <!--Código de Municipio de 5 dígitos: [07065, 07901,...]-->
          <!--Si el país es España (ESP), el código de municipio ha de ir informado, no así el nombre del municipio-->
          <codigoMunicipio>00000</codigoMunicipio>
          <!--Si el país es distinto de España (ESP), ha de informar el nombre del municipio, no así el código de municipio-->
          <nombreMunicipio>texto</nombreMunicipio>
          <codigoPostal>00000</codigoPostal>
          <!--País código ISO alfa-3: [ESP, ARG, ...]-->
          <pais>ESP</pais>
        </direccion>
        <telefono>999999999</telefono>
        <telefono2>999999999</telefono2>
        <correo>correo@correo.es</correo>
        <!--Tipos de parentescos: [AB, BA, BN, CY, CD, HR, HJ, PM, NI, SB, SG, TI, YN, TU, OT]-->
        <parentesco>PM</parentesco>
      </persona>
    </comunicacion>
  </solicitud>
</ns2:peticion>

Esta es la plantilla que hay que generar.

Quería preguntarte si has logrado adelantar algo. Yo estoy un poco parecido, he intentado conectarme mediante CURL y file_get_transfers pero también me da error de autorización.
Después de mucho leer, creo que es porque el archivo .pem no es el correcto, aunque no logro entender de dónde debemos sacarlo.
Por otro lado, lo que seguro tienes mal es que verify_peer debe valer true.
Gracias por cualquier información extra que puedas portar. U saludo

Si, logre conectar correctamente.
Básicamente, el error es que el entorno de pruebas no funciona :-(
Por casualidad cambie al entorno de producción y logre conectar por CURL aunque por SOAP no lo he logrado, de momento tengo suficiente.
Te mando un código básico.
